# How can one open a serial port on Linux using Python and wait for a device to connect?

Tags: python, linux, windows, serial-port, pyserial

I am using pyserial to successfully talk to devices where I am the receiver of information.  I have a piece of windows software that opens a connection over USB/Serial.  I want to wait for it to connect to my linux machine, detect that is connected and begin streaming information to the new device.

On windows it will be looking for a COM port (i.e. COM4) and a baud rate i.e. 38400.  When I attempt to initiate the connection from the Windows machine while the USB cables are connected, there is no device created in /dev on Linux

Am I missing some steps in the process?  Without a device there I'm unsure how to use PySerial to do something like the following:

```
serialOut = serial.Serial(port='/dev/ttyUSB0', baudrate=38400)
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "connect" here?  There is no "connect" signal that is sent on an RS-232 port.  You can monitor handshaking lines such as carrier detect or DSR/CTS to determine if they are asserted but there is no guarantee that this will take place.

Comment: I realize there is no connect signal, but how do I keep something alive on the linux side, have a USB cable between the two, and let the windows side connect to it.  Simply trying to connect to COMX on the windows side won't work.